# c# reports mysql command failed even though it didn't

Tags: c#, mysql

I split the command over several lines for ease of editing:

```
string docommand = "";
docommand += "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `config`;";
//docommand += "/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;";
//docommand += "/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;";
docommand += "CREATE TABLE `config` (";
docommand += "  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,";
docommand += "  `value` varchar(200) NOT NULL,";
docommand += "  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,";
docommand += "  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)";
docommand += ")";
//docommand += " ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
docommand += ";";
//docommand += "/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;";

mysql_connect connect = new mysql_connect();
MySqlConnection conn = connect.connect(core_config.server, core_config.database, core_config.username, core_config.pass);
bool success = mysql_command.command(docommand, conn);
connect.disconnect();

if (!success)
    Console.WriteLine("Command failed : " + docommand);
```

As you can see I commented out a few lines to see if they were causing trouble. Didn't make a difference.

Output:

```
Returning false because resultSet is 0
Command failed : DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `config`;CREATE TABLE `config` (  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,  `value` varchar(200) NOT NULL,  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`));
```

But the table is correctly created... and when I paste the exact same command in `phpmyadmin` and run it from there, it reports no problems whatsoever.

A command like `"SELECT * FROM config"` does not report a failure. So why does the CREATE TABLE command do?

**mysql_command.command()** function:

```
public static bool command(string input, MySqlConnection con)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(input, con);
        var resultSet = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (!resultSet.Equals(0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Returning false because resultSet is 0");
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("MySQL command error : "+ex.Message); }
    Console.WriteLine("Returning false after exception");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both** DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE do not send back anything other than 0. Therefore your "command" method will always believe the command fails. The ExecuteNonQuery() will returns the **rows** affected by your statements, which will be 0.

What you could do, in pass in the amount of rows you expect it to change, so something like:

```
public static bool command(string input, MySqlConnection con, int expectedRowsAffected = 0)
{
try
{
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(input, con);
    var resultSet = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (resultSet.Equals(expectedRowsAffected))
    {
        return true;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Returning false because resultSet isn't {0}", expectedRowsAffected));
    return false;
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("MySQL command error : "+ex.Message); 
}
Console.WriteLine("Returning false after exception");
return false;
```

}

This is not a great way of doing it - as I said, whether or not a command is "successful" can mean different things - but at a low level, a command is successful if it runs without any errors/exceptions, which you are already checking.

Comment: Didn't know that ;O Is there a way for me to check if *any* command whatsoever was succesful / failed ?

Comment: No, because whether it's successful or not depends on what the command is. For example, an update command is successful if it updates the amount of rows you expect, but a CREATE TABLE command is successful if that table now exists as you would expect. However, if you SQL you pass into command is not valid, then it will throw a SQLException. So you can figure out if a command was actually executed with no errors by ensuring no exceptions were thrown, but whether or not it executed successfully/in the way you expect is down to you.

Comment: I edited my answer. Thinking about it, you could pass in how many rows you expect it to affect, and change your return values based on this. Short answer is that I would stick with how you are already doing it, but just change your success checking in the case of special commands, such as the DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE.